# Ruby - escape a number leading variable name

Tags: ruby

I'm using create() to insert into a table that already exists, but some of the table fields and variable names start with a number. Currently in Ruby I'm getting a syntax error "unexpected tIDENTIFIER" when I try to do something like the following-

```
foo.each do |x|
 Object.create(
      3pm: x.3pm,
      3pa: x.3pa
    )
end
```

If I change it to `'3pm' => x.3pm`, it gives me a syntax error on the `x.3pm` portion.

How could I escape this to get it functioning?

Comment: What is foo? Can you show what's the data in `foo`?

Comment: Also, `3pm:` is not a valid hash key, so you'll have to make it a string: `'3pm' =>`. Now, your code will only work if `x` respond to method `3pm` or `3am` accordingly. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: foo is an array of OpenStruct objects. Code is taking a JSON feed and converting it to OpenStruct so I don't think it'd be much benefit to show all of that.

Comment: @Surya `3pm` is not a valid method name, so it doesn't matter whether the object responds to that or not.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info I couldn't find that. I'll find a workaround by modifying the JSON feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `3pm` is not a [valid identifier](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#ident) in Ruby. In Ruby, symbol literals declared with the `:name` syntax and method names must both be valid identifiers.

In the case of the keys, you can get around this by either using strings instead, as you discovered, or by using the `:'name'` syntax for symbol literals:

```
foo.each do |x|
 Object.create(
      :'3pm' => x.3pm,
      :'3pa' => x.3pa
    )
end
```

Unfortunately, this still leaves the problem of `3pm` and `3pa` not being valid method names. Normally, since those are not valid methods names, they couldn't even be methods on `x` in the first place. In this case though, `x` is likely using the either the [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method) or [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) features of Ruby to create or simulate the existance of a method named `3pm` (even though that's normally not a valid method name in Ruby).

Thankfully, we can get around this by using [Object#public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) to call the method:

```
foo.each do |x|
 Object.create(
      :'3pm' => x.public_send(:'3pm'),
      :'3pa' => x.public_send(:'3pa')
    )
end
```

That should resolve your problem.

Comment: It's somewhat unfortunate that Ruby lets you `define_method` with an invalid identifier.

Comment: @Max Yeah, I initially assumed that to be impossible too when I was writing my answer. I was pretty surprised when I tried it in IRB and found that it doesn't raise an error.